# Choosing File To Upload In Protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium, testing, protractor

How can I choose and upload file with file opener in protractor ?
I have done this but it doesn't work :

```
element(by.buttonText('Choose File')).click();
element(by.css('input[type="file"]')).sendKeys('/home/amir/Pictures/peyvast.png');
```

Comment: Have you check the documentation part about file upload ? See http://www.protractortest.org/#/faq#how-can-i-test-file-uploads-

Comment: Does it show any stacktrace? what is the error?